# Sun 280R architecture

Tags: architecture, sun, ultrasparc

How do I find out which architecture my Sun 280R is based on (eg . 501-6485 or 501-6690 etc)
The command arch returns "sun4". Im running Solaris 10
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The architecture **is** `sun4u` for all 280R systems. The part numbers you listed are for 1200MHz UltraSPARC III Cu Module, and as long as you use the same CPU speed you can use modules with different part numbers.

If you want to see processor speed you can use either `prtdiag` or `psrinfo -v`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the prtconf command?

Comment: prtconf gives the system configuration as : Sun Microsystem sun4u
and comes up with a list of system peripherals. nothing about architecture ...